# if else in select sql statement

Tags: sql

I need to show different messages based on the status in the table.

e.g. if the status is 3 in table A, I need to show "Done", if the status is 0, then "Pending". How can I achieve in select statement.

Thanks

Comment: In most RDBMS you would use `CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 'Done' WHEN status = 0 THEN 'Pending' END` but Oracle also has `DECODE()`.

Comment: Did you do any research at all on this? searching for CASE STMT and you're DB would probably point you to exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE...WHEN STMT:

```
 CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 'Done' WHEN status = 0 THEN 'Pending' END
```